# How to connect to remote desktop and copy file from one folder to another folder(Run as Elevated) using powershell script

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges

I am doing this to copy the files from one folder in Remote server D:/ to another folder in same Remote server D:/
1. I open the Windows Powershell by right clicking on the powershell.exe and then select "Run Elevated(Audited)" from this location C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
2. Run these commands : (Referred: https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
```

After running this command it prompt me to enter an option
WinRM Security Configuration.
This command modifies the TrustedHosts list for the WinRM client. The computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. The client might send credential
 information to these computers. Are you sure that you want to modify this list?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

```
Restart-Service WinRM Test-WsMan server-ip(my server ip goes here)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.82.ipaddress -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item -Path D:\Sett-Trans-New\InputFiles\Transmission\KDV\OasisNITS\Positive.csv -Destination D:\Sett-Trans-New\InputFiles\Transmission\KDV\OasisNITS\1\Positive.csv; } -credential username
```

This is working fine when I open the powershell in Elevated mode. I want to convert this into powershell.ps1 and run the script in powershell

The above code runs just fine in powershell when I type one after another, but I am not sure how to run this as a powershell script, when I try to copy paste to sample.ps1 file and execute it as "& C:\Users\V70070\Desktop\script3.ps1" I am getting error as "Connecting to remote server 10.ip-address failed with the following error message : Access is denied"

Any help is highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: I tried to reformat the code such that it would be readable enough from which to comment.

Comment: Thanks for reformatting. The above code runs just fine in powershell when I type one after another, but I am not sure how to run this as a powershell script, when I try to copy paste to sample.ps1 file and execute it as "& C:\Users\V70070\Desktop\script3.ps1" I am getting error as "Connecting to remote server 10.ip-address failed with the following error message : Access is denied"